# How do I make an onClick event that pops up a alert asking the user if they want to sign out?

Tags: reactjs

So I am making a basic messenging application, and I want the onclick function in component Sidebar to sign a user out whenember they click on the avatar(<Avatar onClick={} src={user.photo} className='sidebar__avatar'/>) , but everytime I try to click on the onclick function, nothing happens. is my code fundamentally sound? my goal is to have a popup window so a user can press yes to sign out, but the pop up is not showing. i tried to presence my code and minimalist as possible, that way there is less clutter/confusion.

```
import React from 'react'
import Signout from './Signout'

export function Sidebar(props) {
    return (
        <div/>
             <Avatar onClick={<Signout/>} src={user.photo} className='sidebar__avatar'/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Alert from '@material-ui/lab/Alert';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { auth } from "./firebase"

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
      width: '100%',
      '& > * + *': {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
      },
    },
  }));

export default function Signout(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();

     return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Alert
        action={
          <Button color="inherit" size="small">
            Yes
          </Button>
        }
      >
        Are you sure you want to sign out?
      </Alert>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to render a modal over the current items on the page, is this correct? If so, then check out this documentation for MUI Modals: https://material-ui.com/components/modal/
Also, your on click will need to change a global state in order do this.

Comment: @NathanSutherland Yes! this is perfect, i am using material-ui also so this is awesome, will start with this link

Comment: @NathanSutherland "Also, your on click will need to change a global state in order do this."  i see what you are saying, it has to be set to global state or else the pop out may look funky since itl pop up in the react component?

Comment: I love MUI, so happy you are using it. Nevermind, I just realized that you are only calling the popup in one component. I would move the the modal below the avatar, and then control state there.